# Is lim^1 trivial when this inverse limit is trivial?

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, exact-sequence

I have a tower of abelian groups where for a certain $A_n$, the long exact sequence [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lim%5E1+and+Milnor+sequences#Lim1ViaCokernel) holds:

$0 \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n A_n \longrightarrow \underset{n}{\prod} A_n \stackrel{\partial}{\longrightarrow} \underset{n}{\prod} A_n \longrightarrow \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}^1_n A_n \to 0$

I also know that for my particular $A_n$, first term in the sequence (the inverse limit) is trivial. Thus, $\partial$ is injective. Does that mean that $\partial$ is an isomorphism? This would be based on the assumption that both products are the same size. Is this false?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! Thank you for a well written, nicely typeset question and for sharing your thoughts about the probem.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I found this community while my school is on Christmas vacation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the inverse limit being trivial doesn't tell you anything about $\lim^1$.  For instance, consider the system with $A_n=\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$ and all the maps are multiplication by $2$; then the inverse limit is trivial since the only element of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is infinitely divisible by $2$ is $0$.  Then $\partial$ will be the map $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ that sends $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$ to $(a_0-2a_1,a_1-2a_2,a_2-2a_3,\dots)$.  This is not surjective: for instance, its image does not contain the sequence $(1,0,1,0,\dots)$ that alternates between $1$s and $0$s. (Proving this is a nice exercise.)

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for the perfect, simple example. I used it to at least find a condition I could add that would make $\lim^1$ zero: $\\$ "If the maps of the system of abelian groups are all inclusion maps and if the inverse limit is zero, then $\lim^1$ is zero." That's correct, right? For example, the system of: $\cdots 8\mathbb{Z} \subset 4\mathbb{Z} \subset 2\mathbb{Z} \subset  \mathbb{Z}$ (I cannot think of an example of a system of strict inclusions of abelian groups with a non-trivial inverse limit, though.)

Comment: No, that condition is incorrect: your example is isomorphic to yours (identify $A_n$ with the subgroup $2^n\mathbb{Z}$ of $A_0$).

Comment: Yes, of course! (I give up for today then.) Thank you!